# Python - How to read webpage content after authentication or login?

Tags: python, selenium, mechanize

I am trying to login to a website and read the contents of its webpage(which comes up after I login) using Python. I have got the login part but I'm not able to read the webpage contents. I have tried using urlopen(url). But it again opens the login page. Might be due to authentication being required.

I need help on reading the webpage which opens after logging in.

Comment: So are you using `selenium` or `mechanize` to open the page?

Comment: What do you mean by reading the page? You can use BeautifulSoup to scrape the page.

Comment: I am using selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "requests" package with your url

```
[~]$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 17 2013, 17:31:54) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>> 
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.content
'<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world\'s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you\'re looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="/logos/doodles/2015/eiji-tsuburayas-114th-birthday-4809204506296320.2-hp.jpg" itemprop="image"><meta content="Make a movie with Eiji Tsuburaya! #GoogleDoodle" property="og:description"><meta content="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/eiji-tsuburayas-114th-birthday-4809204506296320.2-hp.jpg" property="og:image"><meta content="356" property="og:image:width"><meta content="200" property="og:image:height"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:\'QuybVeO7Osy4sAXDxIKQCg\',kEXPI:\'18168,3700062,3700306,4020727,4029815,4032235,4032500,4032678,4033307,4033344,4034631,4034882,4036363,4036366,4036470,4036848,4036948,4037333,4037457,4037855,4037921,4037960,4038777,4039047,4039280,4039379,4039386,4039403,4039706,4039878,4040028,4040117,4040135,4040240,8300096,8300200,8300202,8500394,8501295,8501406,8501489,10200083,10201088,10201270,10201302,10201304\',authuser:0,kscs:\'c9c918f0_10\'};google.kHL=\'en\';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,d,e,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,d,e,g);if(""!=a){b=new Image;var c=google.lc,f=google.li;c[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete c[f]};window.google&&window.google.vel&&window.google.vel.lu&&window.google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,d,e,g){var c="",f=google.ls||"";if(!d&&-1==b.search("&ei=")){var h=google.getEI(e),c="&ei="+h;-1==b.search("&lei=")&&((e=google.getLEI(e))?c+="&lei="+e:h!=google.kEI&&(c+="&lei="+google.kEI))}a=d||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+c+f+"&zx="+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1};google.load=function(a,b,d){google.x({id:a+k++},function(){google.load(a,b,d)})};var k=0;})();google.kCSI={};var _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var a=_gjwl.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=a&&(a=_gjwl.href.substring(a),0<a.indexOf("&q=")||0<=a.indexOf("#q="))&&(a=a.substring(1),-1==a.indexOf("#"))){for(var d=0;d<a.length;){var b=d;"&"==a.charAt(b)&&++b;var c=a.indexOf("&",b);-1==c&&(c=a.length);b=a.substring(b,c);if(0==b.indexOf("fp="))a=a.substring(0,d)+a.substring(c,a.length),c=d;else if("cad=h"==b)return 0;d=c}_gjwl.href="/search?"+a+"&cad=h";return 1}return 0}\nfunction _gjh(){!_gjuc()&&window.google&&google.x&&google.x({id:"GJH"},function(){google.nav&&google.nav.gjh&&google.nav.gjh()})};window._gjh&&_gjh();</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}\n</style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff !important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/srpr/nav_logo80.png) 0 -258px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}</style><script></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/searchahead-js/css/searchaheadbox.css"/>\r\n<!--[if IE 6]>\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/searchahead-js/css/searchaheadbox_ie6.css"/>\r\n<![endif]-->\r\n<!--[if IE 7]>\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/searchahead-js/css/searchaheadbox_ie7.css"/>\r\n<![endif]-->\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/searchahead-js/searchaheadAll.min.js"></script></head><body bgcolor="#fff"><script>(function(){var src=\'/images/nav_logo199.png\';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}\nif (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}\n}\n})();</script><div id="mngb">    <div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>Search</b> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi">Images</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl">Maps</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8">Play</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn">News</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/"><u>More</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a href="http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en" class=gb4>Web History</a> | <a  href="/preferences?hl=en" class=gb4>Settings</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.com/" class=gb4>Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div>    </div><center><span id="prt" style="display:block"> <div><style>.pmoabs{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #E5E5E5;color:#666;font-size:13px;padding-bottom:20px;position:absolute;right:2px;top:3px;z-index:986}#pmolnk{border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px}.kd-button-submit{border:1px solid #3079ed;background-color:#4d90fe;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4d90fe),to(#4787ed));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=\'#4d90fe\',EndColorStr=\'#4787ed\')}.kd-button-submit:hover{border:1px solid #2f5bb7;background-color:#357ae8;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#4d90fe),to(#357ae8));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);background-image:linear-gradient(top,#4d90fe,#357ae8);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=\'#4d90fe\',EndColorStr=\'#357ae8\')}.kd-button-submit:active{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)}#pmolnk a{color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;padding:5px 20px;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap}.xbtn{color:#999;cursor:pointer;font-size:23px;line-height:5px;padding-top:5px}.padi{padding:0 8px 0 10px}.padt{padding:5px 20px 0 0;color:#444}.pads{text-align:left;max-width:200px}</style> <div class="pmoabs" id="pmocntr2" style="behavior:url(#default#userdata);display:none"> <table border="0"> <tr> <td colspan="2"> <div class="xbtn" onclick="google.promos&&google.promos.toast&& google.promos.toast.cpc()" style="float:right">&times;</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class="padi" rowspan="2"> <img src="/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png"> </td> <td class="pads">A faster way to browse the web</td> </tr> <tr> <td class="padt"> <div class="kd-button-submit" id="pmolnk"> <a href="/chrome/index.html?hl=en&amp;brand=CHNG&amp;utm_source=en-hpp&amp;utm_medium=hpp&amp;utm_campaign=en" onclick="google.promos&&google.promos.toast&& google.promos.toast.cl()">Install Google Chrome</a> </div> </td> </tr> </table> </div> <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var a={s:{}};a.s.va=50;a.s.ra=10;a.s.aa="body";a.s.Ra=!0;a.s.Ua=function(b,c){var d=a.s.Ha();a.s.Ja(d,b,c);a.s.Va(d);a.s.Ra&&a.s.Sa(d)};a.s.Va=function(b){(b=a.s.ca(b))&&0<b.forms.length&&b.forms[0].submit()};a.s.Ha=function(){var b=document.createElement("iframe");b.height=0;b.width=0;b.style.overflow="hidden";b.style.top=b.style.left="-100px";b.style.position="absolute";document.body.appendChild(b);return b};a.s.ca=function(b){return b.contentDocument||b.contentWindow.document};a.s.Ja=function(b,c,d){b=a.s.ca(b);b.open();d=["<",a.s.aa,\'><form method=POST action="\',d,\'">\'];for(var e in c)c.hasOwnProperty(e)&&d.push(\'<textarea name="\',e,\'">\',c[e],"</textarea>");d.push("</form></",a.s.aa,">");b.write(d.join(""));b.close()};a.s.ea=function(b,c){c>a.s.ra?google&&google.ml&&google.ml(Error("ogcdr"),!1,{cause:"timeout"}):b.contentWindow?a.s.Ta(b):window.setTimeout(function(){a.s.ea(b,c+1)},a.s.va)};a.s.Ta=function(b){document.body.removeChild(b)};a.s.Sa=function(b){a.s.Fa(b,"load",function(){a.s.ea(b,0)})};a.s.Fa=function(b,c,d){b.addEventListener?b.addEventListener(c,d,!1):b.attachEvent&&b.attachEvent("on"+c,d)};var m={Ya:0,G:1,H:2,M:5};a.o={};a.o.O={na:"i",L:"d",pa:"l"};a.o.C={P:"0",I:"1"};a.o.R={N:1,L:2,K:3};a.o.A={ha:"a",la:"g",F:"c",Ba:"u",Aa:"t",P:"p",ta:"pid",ja:"eid",Ca:"at"};a.o.oa=window.location.protocol+"//www.google.com/_/og/promos/";a.o.ka="g";a.o.Da="z";a.o.V=function(b,c,d,e){var f=null;switch(c){case m.G:f=window.gbar.up.gpd(b,d,!0);break;case m.M:f=window.gbar.up.gcc(e)}return null==f?0:parseInt(f,10)};a.o.Na=function(b,c,d){return c==m.G?null!=window.gbar.up.gpd(b,d,!0):!1};a.o.S=function(b,c,d,e,f,h,k,l){var g={};g[a.o.A.P]=b;g[a.o.A.la]=c;g[a.o.A.ha]=d;g[a.o.A.Ca]=e;g[a.o.A.ja]=f;g[a.o.A.ta]=1;k&&(g[a.o.A.F]=k);l&&(g[a.o.A.Ba]=l);if(h)g[a.o.A.Aa]=h;else return google.ml(Error("knu"),!1,{cause:"Token is not found"}),null;return g};a.o.Y=function(b,c,d){if(b){var e=c?a.o.ka:a.o.Da;c&&d&&(e+="?authuser="+d);a.s.Ua(b,a.o.oa+e)}};a.o.Ia=function(b,c,d,e,f,h,k){b=a.o.S(c,b,a.o.O.L,a.o.R.L,d,f,null,e);a.o.Y(b,h,k)};a.o.La=function(b,c,d,e,f,h,k){b=a.o.S(c,b,a.o.O.na,a.o.R.N,d,f,e,null);a.o.Y(b,h,k)};a.o.Qa=function(b,c,d,e,f,h,k,l,g,n){switch(c){case m.M:window.gbar.up.dpc(e,f);break;case m.G:window.gbar.up.spd(b,d,1,!0);break;case m.H:g=g||!1,l=l||"",h=h||0,k=k||a.o.C.I,n=n||0,a.o.Ia(e,h,k,f,l,g,n)}};a.o.Oa=function(b,c,d,e,f){return c==m.G?0<d&&a.o.V(b,c,e,f)>=d:!1};a.o.Ka=function(b,c,d,e,f,h,k,l,g,n){switch(c){case m.M:window.gbar.up.iic(e,f);break;case m.G:c=a.o.V(b,c,d,e)+1;window.gbar.up.spd(b,d,c.toString(),!0);break;case m.H:g=g||!1,l=l||"",h=h||0,k=k||a.o.C.P,n=n||0,a.o.La(e,h,k,1,l,g,n)}};a.o.Pa=function(b,c,d,e,f,h){b=a.o.S(c,b,a.o.O.pa,a.o.R.K,d,e,null,null);a.o.Y(b,f,h)};var p={Wa:"a",Za:"l",Xa:"c",ia:"d",K:"h",N:"i",jb:"n",I:"x",gb:"ma",hb:"mc",ib:"mi",$a:"pa",ab:"pc",cb:"pi",fb:"pn",eb:"px",bb:"pd",kb:"gpa",mb:"gpi",nb:"gpn",ob:"gpx",lb:"gpd"};a.i={};a.i.w={qa:"hplogo",za:"pmocntr2"};a.i.C={ya:"0",I:"1",ga:"2"};a.i.v=document.getElementById(a.i.w.za);a.i.ma=16;a.i.wa=2;a.i.xa=20;google.promos=google.promos||{};google.promos.toast=google.promos.toast||{};a.i.J=function(b){a.i.v&&(a.i.v.style.display=b?"":"none",a.i.v.parentNode&&(a.i.v.parentNode.style.position=b?"relative":""))};a.i.fa=function(b){try{if(a.i.v&&b&&b.es&&b.es.m){var c=window.gbar.rtl(document.body)?"left":"right";a.i.v.style[c]=b.es.m-a.i.ma+a.i.wa+"px";a.i.v.style.top=a.i.xa+"px"}}catch(d){google.ml(d,!1,{cause:a.i.B+"_PT"})}};google.promos.toast.cl=function(){try{a.i.T==m.H&&a.o.Pa(a.i.W,a.i.D,a.i.C.ga,a.i.$,a.i.X,a.i.Z),window.gbar.up.sl(a.i.D,a.i.B,p.K,a.i.U(),1)}catch(b){google.ml(b,!1,{cause:a.i.B+"_CL"})}};google.promos.toast.cpc=function(){try{a.i.v&&(a.i.J(!1),a.o.Qa(a.i.v,a.i.T,a.i.w.ba,a.i.W,a.i.Ga,a.i.D,a.i.C.I,a.i.$,a.i.X,a.i.Z),window.gbar.up.sl(a.i.D,a.i.B,p.ia,a.i.U(),1))}catch(b){google.ml(b,!1,{cause:a.i.B+"_CPC"})}};a.i.da=function(){try{if(a.i.v){var b=276,c=document.getElementById(a.i.w.qa);c&&(b=Math.max(b,c.offsetWidth));var d=parseInt(a.i.v.style.right,10)||0;a.i.v.style.visibility=2*(a.i.v.offsetWidth+d)+b>document.body.clientWidth?"hidden":""}}catch(e){google.ml(e,!1,{cause:a.i.B+"_HOSW"})}};a.i.Ea=function(){var b=["gpd","spd","aeh","sl"];if(!window.gbar||!window.gbar.up)return!1;for(var c=0,d;d=b[c];c++)if(!(d in window.gbar.up))return!1;return!0};a.i.Ma=function(){return a.i.v.currentStyle&&"absolute"!=a.i.v.currentStyle.position};google.promos.toast.init=function(b,c,d,e,f,h,k,l,g,n,q,r){try{if(!a.i.Ea())google.ml(Error("apa"),!1,{cause:a.i.B+"_INIT"});else if(a.i.v)if(e==m.H&&!l==!g)google.ml(Error("tku"),!1,{cause:"zwieback: "+g+", gaia: "+l}),a.i.J(!1);else if(a.i.w.F="toast_count_"+c+(q?"_"+q:""),a.i.w.ba="toast_dp_"+c+(r?"_"+r:""),a.i.B=d,a.i.D=b,a.i.T=e,a.i.W=c,a.i.Ga=f,a.i.$=l?l:g,a.i.X=!!l,a.i.Z=k,a.o.Na(a.i.v,e,a.i.w.ba,c)||a.o.Oa(a.i.v,e,h,a.i.w.F,c)||a.i.Ma())a.i.J(!1);else{a.o.Ka(a.i.v,e,a.i.w.F,c,f,a.i.D,a.i.C.ya,a.i.$,a.i.X,a.i.Z);if(!n){try{window.gbar.up.aeh(window,"resize",a.i.da)}catch(u){}window.lol=a.i.da;window.gbar.elr&&a.i.fa(window.gbar.elr());window.gbar.elc&&window.gbar.elc(a.i.fa);a.i.J(!0)}window.gbar.up.sl(a.i.D,a.i.B,p.N,a.i.U())}}catch(t){google.ml(t,!1,{cause:a.i.B+"_INIT"})}};a.i.U=function(){var b=a.o.V(a.i.v,a.i.T,a.i.w.F,a.i.W);return"ic="+b};})();</script> <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var sourceWebappPromoID=144002;var sourceWebappGroupID=5;var payloadType=5;var cookieMaxAgeSec=2592000;var dismissalType=5;var impressionCap=25;var gaiaXsrfToken=\'\';var zwbkXsrfToken=\'\';var kansasDismissalEnabled=false;var sessionIndex=0;var invisible=false;window.gbar&&gbar.up&&gbar.up.r&&gbar.up.r(payloadType,function(show){if (show){google.promos.toast.init(sourceWebappPromoID,sourceWebappGroupID,payloadType,dismissalType,cookieMaxAgeSec,impressionCap,sessionIndex,gaiaXsrfToken,zwbkXsrfToken,invisible,\'0612\');}\n});})();</script> </div> </span><br clear="all" id="lgpd"><div id="lga"><a href="/search?site=&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;q=Eiji+Tsuburaya&amp;oi=ddle&amp;ct=eiji-tsuburayas-114th-birthday-4809204506296320&amp;hl=en&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=QuybVeO7Osy4sAXDxIKQCg&amp;ved=0CAMQNg"><img alt="Eiji Tsuburaya&#8217;s 114th Birthday" border="0" height="200" src="/logos/doodles/2015/eiji-tsuburayas-114th-birthday-4809204506296320.2-hp.jpg" title="Eiji Tsuburaya&#8217;s 114th Birthday" width="356" id="hplogo" onload="window.lol&&lol()"><br></a><br></div><form action="/search" name="f"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr valign="top"><td width="25%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center" nowrap=""><input name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" type="hidden"><input value="en" name="hl" type="hidden"><input name="source" type="hidden" value="hp"><input name="biw" type="hidden"><input name="bih" type="hidden"><div class="ds" style="height:32px;margin:4px 0"><input style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top" autocomplete="off" class="lst" value="" title="Google Search" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57"></div><br style="line-height:0"><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="Google Search" name="btnG" type="submit"></span></span><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="I\'m Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" onclick="if(this.form.q.value)this.checked=1; else top.location=\'/doodles/\'" type="submit"></span></span></td><td class="fl sblc" align="left" nowrap="" width="25%"><a href="/advanced_search?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Advanced search</a><a href="/language_tools?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Language tools</a></td></tr></table><input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1"></form><div id="gac_scont"></div><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br></div><span id="footer"><div style="font-size:10pt"><div style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center" id="fll"><a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising&nbsp;Programs</a><a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a><a href="https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550" rel="publisher">+Google</a><a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a></div></div><p style="color:#767676;font-size:8pt">&copy; 2015 - <a href="/intl/en/policies/privacy/">Privacy</a> - <a href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a></p></span></center><script>(function(){window.google.cdo={height:0,width:0};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b)var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body,a=d.clientWidth,b=d.clientHeight;a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)&&google.log("","","/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI);})();})();</script><div id="xjsd"></div><div id="xjsi" data-jiis="bp"><script>(function(){function c(b){window.setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src=b;document.getElementById("xjsd").appendChild(a)},0)}google.dljp=function(b,a){google.xjsu=b;c(a)};google.dlj=c;})();(function(){window.google.xjsrm=[];})();if(google.y)google.y.first=[];if(!google.xjs){window._=window._||{};window._._DumpException=function(e){throw e};if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dljp(\'/xjs/_/js/k\\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.n4Isykx1pOI.O/m\\x3dsb_he,d/rt\\x3dj/d\\x3d1/t\\x3dzcms/rs\\x3dACT90oGruBlRL4zSGyBzh4XK8InqnND9gA\',\'/xjs/_/js/k\\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.n4Isykx1pOI.O/m\\x3dsb_he,d/rt\\x3dj/d\\x3d1/t\\x3dzcms/rs\\x3dACT90oGruBlRL4zSGyBzh4XK8InqnND9gA\');google.xjs=1;}google.pmc={"sb_he":{"agen":true,"cgen":true,"client":"heirloom-hp","dh":true,"ds":"","fl":true,"host":"google.com","jam":0,"jsonp":true,"msgs":{"cibl":"Clear Search","dym":"Did you mean:","lcky":"I\\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky","lml":"Learn more","oskt":"Input tools","psrc":"This search was removed from your \\u003Ca href=\\"/history\\"\\u003EWeb History\\u003C/a\\u003E","psrl":"Remove","sbit":"Search by image","srch":"Google Search"},"ovr":{},"pq":"","refoq":true,"refpd":true,"rfs":[],"scd":10,"sce":5,"stok":"zjtqyOq-JYCOTkhf-6zvDRQ7OsI"},"d":{}};google.y.first.push(function(){if(google.med){google.med(\'init\');google.initHistory();google.med(\'history\');}});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);}\n</script></div></body></html>'
>>>
```

Sorry for the content is too long :) But it's really pure string.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to open a url using selenium by creating a webdriver

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile) 
browser.get(url)
```

In that case if you just say "browser.page_source" it should get the page source. But make sure that you wait until the page is loaded before reading the pagesource.

Answer (score -1):

To test the behavior in your webpage. I suggest you use BDD Javascript Framework like CasperJs/PhantomJS